# Как разрешить шорткоды в мета-тегах title и description в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется WordPress 5.4 и плагин All In One SEO Pack.
Мне нужно добавить шорткод в title и description на одну страницу.
Конструкции вида `[sitename]` и `<?php echo do_shortcode('[sitename]');?>` не срабатывают, ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 0):

Для заголовка:

```
add_filter('aioseo_title', 'aioseo_filter_title');
function aioseo_filter_title($title)
{
return do_shortcode($title);
}
```

Для описания:

```
add_filter('aioseo_description', 'aioseo_filter_description');

function aioseo_filter_description($description)
{
return do_shortcode($description);
}
```